# Increase rlimit Mac OSX 10.8

Tags: macos, mongodb, osx-mountain-lion

I'm learning MongoDB and when I start the mongo shell a wild warning message appeared. It says:
[image]

How do i change the "soft rlimits". I'm using Mac OSX 10.8.2

Tnx in advance

Comment: The warning on limits here shouldn't affect you unless you are working with a larger number of data files/connections.  The default OS X limits are generally fine for learning or development purposes.

Comment: You are right, However I don't like see any warnings :) (even in dev mode)

Comment: @ingcarlos +1 cuz i thought i was the only one :-P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are searching for is `launchctl limit maxfiles`.
To change it you need to run command `launchctl limit maxfiles 1024 2048` for example.
To permanently change those values you need to create /etc/launchctl.conf and set there values you need (see [here](http://www.g9labs.com/2012/06/20/updating-max-file-limit-on-osx-lion/) for details) or add command mentioned above to your ~/.bash_profile.
Or you can create script which will set limit and then launch mongo

Comment: This did not work for me on OSX 10.8.4. If anyone else has trouble `ulimit -n 1024` did the trick

Comment: the above command needs to be executed as root (not via sudo).

Comment: I would not recommend setting the hard limit to 2048, it did lock my system (Yosemite). Silly me for running a command without double-checking! Run "launchctl limit maxfiles" to see the current limits and then change only the soft limit, e.g. in my case I had "256 unlimited" (first is soft, second is hard), so I ran "sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 1024 unlimited". Which in practice actually set them to "1024 10240".
So in the end, using just "ulimit -n 1024" (without sudo) worked fine for my own user that's running MongoDB... sounds like a better solution than changing system-wide settings.

Comment: Just to pipe in to say that @Kamal and @jwags are quite right, and using `ulimit -n 1024` is the preferred option; their comments ought to be turned into answers!

Answer (score 1):

If you run mongo as a service, you can configure the max open files by adding the next lines to the

> /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.mongodb.mongod.plist

```
  <key>SoftResourceLimits</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NumberOfFiles</key>
    <integer>1024</integer>
  </dict>
```

and restart the service

Comment: In my case the file was _/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.mongo.mongod.plist_, everthing else is the same.

For restarting the service please refer: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/194832/how-to-start-stop-restart-launchd-services-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Having faced similar issues, and after a lot of searches, I found [this](https://gist.github.com/tamitutor/6a1e41eec0ce021a9718) answer useful.

This gist explains how to address this issue via dedicated launch files as well as session only changes.