# Mac OSX - mongod and mongo not working

Tags: macos, mongodb

I'm completely new to databases and am trying to set up mongodb.
I've followed all the steps but neither the mongod or mongo commands work.

This is the output from mongod:

```
ERROR: could not read from config file
```

That is followed by all the mongo options (-h, -f, -v, etc.)

This is the output from mongo:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: test
Fri Sep  6 22:55:35.889 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What command did you use while trying to start `mongod`?

Comment: I just used the `mongod` command in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting mongod with --config option specified. Something like `/path/to/mongod --config /path/to/mongodb.conf`.

In your mongodb.config check the location to the mongodb log. You should find additional details about errors there. Possible problems are: db path does not exist or is not writable, after an unclean shutdown mongod.lock file still exists etc.

Comment: ok, I ran `/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/bin/mongod` and after creating the `/data/db` folder, it seems to work. It still warns me that the soft rlimits are too low... what does that mean?

Comment: @August You should probably change limit on max. number of open files. There are several questions about this topic on SO.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939885/increase-rlimit-mac-osx-10-8
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420073/mongod-runs-but-mongo-returns-an-error